# Is it possible to see all active rules from a complex eslint config?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

My eslint configuration extends several other configuration files. Is it possible to get a static export of all the currently applied rules?

Is there possibly a VSCode plugin for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the --print-config option.

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config some-file.js > my-config.json
```

or

```
npx eslint --print-config some-file.js > my-config.json
```